# Getting script (SQL Server object) into a variable in PowerShell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I need to get a script from a urn object into a variable in order to persist in the database.

When I try to persist, the script column is null.

The part of the code that I'm stuck is:

```
Foreach ($tb in $db.Tables)
{
       If ($tb.IsSystemObject -eq $FALSE)
       {
              $smoObjects.Add($tb.Urn)

              ########  add the scripts (obj) to table ########

              $Script = Write-Output $scrp.Script($tb.Urn)
              $Table = $tb

              $insertquery = "INSERT INTO $tableInsertName ([VersionDate], [DBName], [TableName], [Script]) VALUES ('$DateInsert', '$db', '$Table', '$Script')"
              $Command.CommandText = $insertquery

              $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
       }
}
```

Any ideas please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to output `$insertquery` instead of executing it? Does it look the way it should?

Comment: The $insertquery is suppose to be executed in order to persist the database, the issue is when I pass the value $Script, which is null at the DB. I need to get the script from $scrp.Script($tb.Urn) and insert into the table.

Comment: I know. I'm trying to help you _debug_ what is going wrong. You currently say `$Command.CommandText = $insertquery` and then blindly `$Command.ExecuteNonQuery()`. Try _outputting_ `$insertquery` instead of executing so that you can examine exactly what it is you're blindly executing. e.g. `Write-Host $insertquery` might give some clue.

Comment: Ohh I see I see, gonna give it a try! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the issue.

The $Script it was null because the variable in the session was like that and used before. I killed the session, rerun the script and worked properly.

I hope it helps someone else.